# Relation between two statistical measures

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

Consider a random variable $X$ with the associated density function $f_X(x)$ and "zero" mean.

Define the following quantities:

(1) $E[X^2] := \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^2 f_X(x) dx$

(2) $E[ |X| ] := \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |x| f_X(x) dx$

I see that $E[X^2]$ is the variance (noting that the mean is zero). But I have no idea if $E[|X|]$ is already well-known and useful in the probability context.

Anyway, here is the question: I wonder if there is some functional (in)equality between $E[X^2]$ and $E[|X|]$. Something of the following form: the existence of a mapping $\rho : \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that $E[|X|] \leq \rho(E[X^2])$.

You may make a fair assumption on the density function $f_X(x)$ if required. The zero mean assumption is made to make the life easier. You may also drop it if necessary.

Comment: This is a special case of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244202.

Comment: $E(|X-\mu|)$ is often called the [mean deviation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeanDeviation.html) or the mean absolute deviation. The relationship between mean deviation and standard deviation is discussed in several questions on site. One example -- though in answer to a narrower question -- is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70879/805); note that the result there uses the standard (convex) version of Jensen's inequality.

Answer (score 1):

By [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) (for concave functions instead of convex functions), we have
$$
E[|X|]
= E[\sqrt{X^2}]
\leq \sqrt{E[X^2]}.
$$
Alternatively, the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Probability_theory) can be used to yield the same ineuqality:
$$
E[|X|]^2
= E[|X|\cdot 1]^2
\leq E[|X|^2] E[1^2]
= E[X^2].
$$
This makes no assumptions on the existence of a probability density or having mean zero (or any mean for that matter).